# Create nested list of DataFrames using for loop and pd.read_excel

Tags: pandas, for-loop

I have 03 folders, each folder contains 03 Excel files.
I have tried to use pd.read_excel to create a nested list of DataFrame from each folder.
My desired output is like ( a nested list containing 03 parent lists, each parent list contains 03 dataframes from each folder) :

```
df_list_concat =[[df_folder_1_file_1,df_folder_1_file_2,df_folder_1_file_3],[df_folder_2_file_1,df_folder_2_file_2,df_folder_2_file_3],[df_folder_3_file_1,df_folder_3_file_2,df_folder_3_file_3]]
```

But my codes result in a list of 09 items:

```
df_list_concat = [df_folder_1_file_1,df_folder_1_file_2,df_folder_1_file_3,df_folder_2_file_1,df_folder_2_file_2,df_folder_2_file_3,df_folder_3_file_1,df_folder_3_file_2,df_folder_3_file_3]
```

My codes :

```
import pandas as pd
import os


path_2016 ='D:/2016'
path_2017 ='D:/2017'
path_2018 ='D:/2018'
path=[path_2016,path_2017,path_2018]

df_list_concat=[]
df_list=[]
for i in range(len(path)):
    for filename in os.listdir(path[i]):
        df=pd.read_excel(f"{path[i]}/{filename}",skiprows=7)
        df_list.append(df)
        df_list_concat.append(df_list)
```

Your help is highly appreciated!!!